# Any null safe alternative to ArrayList.addAll?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I was refactoring some old code of mine that I've written and I stumbeled on this code:

```
    List<OcmImageData> fullImagePool = new ArrayList<>();
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(style.getTestMH())) {
        fullImagePool.addAll(style.getTestMH());
    }
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(style.getTrousers())) {
        fullImagePool.addAll(style.getTrousers());
    }
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(style.getDetailRevers())) {
        fullImagePool.addAll(style.getDetailRevers());
    }
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(style.getDetailCuffs())) {
        fullImagePool.addAll(style.getDetailCuffs());
    }
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(style.getDetailInner())) {
        fullImagePool.addAll(style.getDetailInner());
    }
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(style.getDetailMaterial())) {
        fullImagePool.addAll(style.getDetailMaterial());
    }
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(style.getComposing())) {
        fullImagePool.addAll(style.getComposing());
    }
    ...
```

So basically I need to create an ArrayList which contains all Lists here referenced, because those can be null (they are fetched out of the database from an closed sourced framework, and unfortunately its null if he doesn't find anything), I need to check everytime if the collection is not null to add them into this pool which looks just weird.

Is there a library or Collection-Framework utility class that gives me the posibility to add a collection to another without performing the null-safe check?

Comment: I _strongly_ recommend creating a wrapper around the crappy closed source framework to not return `null`, instead returning an empty list, so you don't have to worry about this ever again.  Using `null` instead of an empty collection is essentially always a terrible idea.

Comment: Why? If null List references are semantically the same as empty Lists, why not just use empty Lists? And if they are semantically different, why do you want to find a library that treats them as semantically the same?

Answer (score 92):

In Java 8 Use below code:-

```
Optional.ofNullable(listToBeAdded).ifPresent(listToBeAddedTo::addAll)
```

listToBeAdded - The list whose elements are to be added.
listToBeAddedTo - The list to which you are adding elements using addAll.

Comment: This is so ugly. I'm just going to set `listToBeAdded` to an empty list if it's null.

Comment: That's cleaner than the OP's code, it fits in one line, it only uses existing java features (and is as readable as the utility function solution). I don't think this is an "ugly" solution. Making each list empty if it's null is uglier, unless you wrap it into a custom List class that perform the whole replacement (which has disadvantages and is heavier to implement). I'd say that the best/cleaner solution depends on how often you need to do such things, but I think this one deserves an upvote.

Comment: I don't think addAll to empty list will work either. e.g `List<ProductReferenceData> spareParts = new ArrayList<ProductReferenceData>(); ` 'spareParts.addAll(componentLabels);' will still throw 'UnsupportedOperationException' when spareParts list is having 0 elements.

Comment: I really think this is an example of where one line is not better.   The utility method approach documented below, reads so much easier.  In my opinion, while this is elegant for those in the "know", it requires way more technical pre-requisite knowledge to be readable and understood.

Answer (score 34):

Just write a small utility method:

```
public static <E> void addAllIfNotNull(List<E> list, Collection<? extends E> c) {
    if (c != null) {
        list.addAll(c);
    }
}
```

so that you can write:

```
List<OcmImageData> fullImagePool = new ArrayList<>();
addAllIfNotNull(fullImagePool, style.getTestMH());
addAllIfNotNull(fullImagePool, style.getTrousers());
addAllIfNotNull(fullImagePool, style.getDetailRevers());
// ...etc
```

Comment: I like the concept and upvoted, but this seems a little too specific to me.  I would write a more general purpose utility,  `convertNullToEmpty(Collection inMightBeNull)`;  (generics omitted for simplicity since this is a comment)).  Then use`fullImagePool.addAll(convertNullToEmpty(style.getXXX()));`

Comment: flawless answer!

Comment: I really love this code.  Very elegant and maintainable solution.

Answer (score 11):

Using Java 8:

```
List<OcmImageData> fullImagePool = Stream.of(style.getTestMH(), /* etc */)
                                         .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                         .flatMap(l -> l.stream())
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You should probably use `CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty` instead of `Objects::nonNull` to keep the OP's semantics.

Comment: I could, but it would cover the beauty of ``flatMap``

Comment: Assuming `CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty` does nothing more (it doesn't really say). However, the question clearly asks for null checks so I guess it is good either way.

Answer (score 6):

This refactors cleanly to

```
for (OcmImageData elem : new List<OcmImageData>[] { style.getTestMH(), style.getTrousers() /* etc */}) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(elem)) {
        fullImagePull.addAll(elem);
    }
}
```

To answer your original question, no, you will have to do your own null check. You can see [Guava's methods will throw an NPE](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/r08/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.java#Iterators.addAll%28java.util.Collection%2Cjava.util.Iterator%29), and Apache's methods [explicitly require the input to be not null](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html).

Comment: @user949300 the null check is not duplicated N times.

Comment: @user949300 and the point of this business logic is to roll up all of style's different attributes into one list, so it should be exactly as long as the number of attributes, but not duplicate the work done to each attribute. Creating an intermediate collection of them is the way to go.

Comment: @djechlin  Your's is an interesting approach, and I see many good features.  But, ideally, the list of all of style's different attributes should be contained within the Style class, not a List you create on the fly.  e.g., the **Style** class should have a `getAllAttributeLists()` method that returns a List (or Array, or some Iterable thingie perhaps from Java 8, could be a list of funtion pointers???) of getTestMH(), getTrousers()...

Comment: @user949300 no, there is no reason to believe the Style class should provide this utility function, or own the logic that the OP's class is performing. Arguably the OP could factor it out into a StyleUtil class. Put simply, the OP does not own Style, which is the point of this question in the first place.

Comment: @djechlin There I have to strongly disagree.  When the 60s return and you add a `style.getBellBottoms()`, my approach only modifies one class, Style, and your modifies two or more and will likely have bugs.  Note: Style just returns the lists.  Checking for null and adding to fullImagePull belongs outside - there I completely agree with you.

Comment: @user949300 but you don't own Style. You can't modify it. That's the OP's question.

Comment: My mistake, you are correct - on rereading I see he doesn't own Style.  I did say "ideally".  Thanks for the suggestion to post an answer, but on further thought if OP does own Style there are a ton of possibly improvements, (Enums for all the sub-styles come to mind) so the answer would be both long and irrelevant.  :-)